# Flutter change state of an item in a ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, listtile

I'm trying to use a ListTile widget inside a ListView that will change depending on some information received elsewhere in the app. In order to practice, I tried to make a little Dartpad example.

The problem is as follows: I have been able to change the booleans and data behind the items, but they don't update within the ListView.builder.

I have ListTile widgets inside the ListView that I want to have four different states as follows: `idle`, `wait`, `requested`, and `speaking`.

The different states look like this, as an example:
[image]

I am trying to change the individual state of one of these items, but I haven't been able to get them to properly update within the ListView.

The ListTile code looks like this. Most of this code is responsible for just handling what the UI should look like for each state:

```
class UserItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String name;
  UserTileState userTileState;
  UserItem(this.name, this.userTileState);

  @override
  UserItemState createState() => UserItemState();
}

class UserItemState extends State<UserItem> {
  String _getCorrectTextState(UserTileState userTileState) {
    switch (userTileState) {
      case UserTileState.speaking:
        return "Currently Speaking";
      case UserTileState.requested:
        return "Speak Request";
      case UserTileState.wait:
        return "Wait - Someone Speaking";
      case UserTileState.idle:
        return "Idle";
    }
  }

  Widget _getCorrectTrailingWidget(UserTileState userTileState) {
    switch (userTileState) {
      case UserTileState.speaking:
        return const CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Icon(Icons.volume_up));
      case UserTileState.requested:
        return CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade100,
          foregroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
        );
      case UserTileState.wait:
        return CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade100,
          foregroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_off),
        );
      case UserTileState.idle:
        return CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade100,
          foregroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
          child: const Icon(Icons.volume_off),
        );
    }
  }

  void kickUser(String name) {
    print("Kick $name");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
        onLongPress: () {
          kickUser(widget.name);
        },
        title: Text(widget.name,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: widget.userTileState == UserTileState.speaking ||
                        widget.userTileState == UserTileState.requested
                    ? FontWeight.bold
                    : FontWeight.normal)),
        subtitle: Text(_getCorrectTextState(widget.userTileState),
            style: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
        trailing: _getCorrectTrailingWidget(widget.userTileState));
  }
}

enum UserTileState { speaking, requested, idle, wait }
```

To try and trigger a change in one of these `UserTile` items, I wrote a function as follows. This one should make an `idle` tile become a `requested` tile.

```
void userRequest(String name) {
    // send a speak request to a tile
    int index = users.indexWhere((element) => element.name == name);
    users[index].userTileState = UserTileState.requested;
  }
```

I will then run that `userRequest` inside my main build function inside a button, as follows:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  void userRequest(String name) {
    // send a speak request to a tile
    int index = users.indexWhere((element) => element.name == name);
    users[index].userTileState = UserTileState.requested;
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Expanded(
          flex: 8,
          child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const Divider();
              },
              itemCount: users.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return users[index];
              })),
      Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        userRequest("Test1");
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text("Send Request")),
                
              ]))
    ]));
  }
}
```

When I tap the button to set the value within the first `UserTile`, nothing happens.

I don't know where to put setState, and the state of the object within the ListView isn't being updated. What is the most simple solution to this problem? Provider? I've used Provider in this same situation and can't get it to work. Is there another simpler solution to this?

How can I change update the state of a specific element within a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that I posted has had mixed results for some. My main project actually is actually a bit more complex and involves `Provider`, but I tried my best to strip the code down to its simplest parts when I posted this question. I'm wondering if something else is getting in the way of this working. (maybe it's because I threw this example together using dartpad?)

In the mean time, I've discovered that adding or removing an element to the list seems to change the entire state of the list. *Using this technique, instead of trying to change an individual value, I get its index, remove it, and re-add it at that index and it works like a charm.* So instead of this:

```
void userRequest(String name) {
    // send a speak request to a tile
    int index = users.indexWhere((element) => element.name == name);
    users[index].userTileState = UserTileState.requested;
  }
```

followed by `setState(() => userRequest("name");`, the following seems to work instead:

```
void userRequest(String name) {
    // send a speak request to a tile
    int index = users.indexWhere((element) => element.name == name);
    users.removeAt(index);
    users.insert(index, UserItem(name, UserTileStates.requested));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use StatefulBuilder() - by using this you will get a separate state for each item in your list, that can be updated

like this:

```
ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const Divider();
          },
          itemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: ((context, setStateItem){

         //return_your_listTile_widget_here
         //use setStateItem (as setState) this will update the state of selected item

                setStateItem(() {
                        //code for update the listView item                 
                       });

                  })
                );
          })),
```

[image]

Comment: The code for updating the listView item is going to be called from a button, not from inside the main build function. The updating is different depending on the button pressed, so I'm not sure how I would put that inside a Stateful Builder.

Comment: I just run your code and changed nothing and its working. Here I'am updating the ListTile first and second with 2 buttons. checkout the attachment

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies here in `_getCorrectTextState()`

Create a variable, `String _status;`
And do something like this;

```
     void _getCorrectTextState(UserTileState userTileState) {
            String tmpState;
            switch (userTileState) {
              case UserTileState.speaking:
                tmpState = "Currently Speaking";
              case UserTileState.requested:
                tmpState = "Speak Request";
              case UserTileState.wait:
                tmpState = "Wait - Someone Speaking";
              case UserTileState.idle:
                tmpState = "Idle";
            }
           setState(() => {_state = tmpState});
}
```

then in your build:

```
subtitle: _state;
```

Comment: This is an idea, but I need to call `_getCorrectTextState` inside the `subtitle` property because the text is different depending on the `userTileState` and I wouldn't have anywhere else to call it.

Comment: Why no adding the logic _getCorrectTrailingWidget()?

Comment: The same problem. I need _getCorrectTrailingWidget to be called in the `trailing` property.